# Search for Folder Containing String and Open

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write a very simple program that requires an entry of 4 digits in a text box and the goal of it is to open a folder that ends with these entered 4 digits.

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
 Private Sub GoBut_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles GoBut.Click

    Dim wdcode As String
    Dim wd_path As String
    Dim design_drive As String

    wdcode = TextCode.Text

    design_drive = "Y:\Sample Code Sequence\"

    wd_path = design_drive & wdcode

    Process.Start("explorer.exe", String.Format("/n, /e, {0}", wd_path))
End Sub
```

I am a relative novice in VB so please keep it fairly straight forward. The folders that I wish to open in explorer are 8 digits long and will be in a sub-directory.

So, to summarise, the folders and sub-folders are in this format:

```
Y:/Sample Code Sequence/1001 - 1100/15061089
Y:/Sample Code Sequence/1001 - 1100/15061090
Y:/Sample Code Sequence/1001 - 1100/15061091
Y:/Sample Code Sequence/1001 - 1100/15071092
....
Y:/Sample Code Sequence/1101 - 1200/15071111
Y:/Sample Code Sequence/1001 - 1100/15071131
etc
```

The last 4 digits of the 8 digit folder names are unique.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function might be better for long-term reusability, but I wrote this as just a nested loop.  It takes your base directory (in your case, "Y:\Sample Code Sequence\") and uses the GetDirectories function of the DirectoryInfo class to return the subdirectories of the base directory.  It then loops through those subdirectories and does the same thing, then returns the full path to that directory if a match is found (or Nothing if a match isn't found).

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Debug.WriteLine(GetSubFolder("c:\temp\test\", 1089))
End Sub

Private Function GetSubFolder(ByVal baseDirectory As String, ByVal searchTerm As String) As String
    Try
        If Not Directory.Exists(baseDirectory) Then Return Nothing

        For Each dirInfo As DirectoryInfo In New DirectoryInfo(baseDirectory).GetDirectories()
            For Each dirInfoSub As DirectoryInfo In dirInfo.GetDirectories()
                If dirInfoSub.Name.Length >= 4 AndAlso _
                    dirInfoSub.Name.Substring(dirInfoSub.Name.Length - 4) = searchTerm _
                    Then Return dirInfoSub.FullName
            Next
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return Nothing
End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t24c0thc.aspx)) which accepts wildcards:

```
Dim found As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories("Y:\Sample Code Sequence\", _
                                      FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, _
                                      "*1089").FirstOrDefault()
MessageBox.Show(found)
```

To apply this you'll need to concatenate the value you are looking for to "*".

You can add further checks; for example, to check that the folder name has 8 characters (ending 1089):

```
Dim found2 As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories("Y:\Sample Code Sequence\", _
                                      FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, _
                                      "*1089").Where(Function(x) x.LastIndexOf("\"c) = x.LastIndexOf("1089") - 5).FirstOrDefault()
MessageBox.Show(found2)
```

This can actually be simplified by searching using `????1089`, where ? is a wildcard character for a single character.

Checking that the folder name is 8 characters, starting with 4 digits, requires a little more work:

```
Dim found3 As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories("Y:\Sample Code Sequence\", _
                                      FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, _
                                      "*1089").Where(Function(x)
                                                         Return x.LastIndexOf("\"c) = x.LastIndexOf("1089") - 5 _
                                                             AndAlso IsNumeric(x.Substring(x.LastIndexOf("\"c) + 1, 4))
                                                     End Function).FirstOrDefault()
MessageBox.Show(found3)
```

It will be easier to follow if you first find the folder(s) and then, separately, check the folder names, rather than as a single statement as I have done.

You should also check for no match, `Nothing`.

Comment: Thanks all

I went for:

        Private Sub GoBut_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles GoBut.Click

        Dim wdcode As String
        wdcode = TextCode.Text

        Dim wd_wild As String
        wd_wild = "*"

        Dim wd_full As String
        wd_full = wd_wild & wdcode

        Dim found As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories("Y:\Sample Code Sequence\", _
                                      FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, wd_full).FirstOrDefault()

        Process.Start("explorer.exe", String.Format("/n, /e, {0}", found))
    End Sub